# Set random seed on Postgres using hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm not very familiar with Hibernate, but I need to set the random seed on a PostgreSQL database using Hibernate.

This is what I'm trying to run:

```
String seedSql = "select setseed(0.123)";
Query seedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(seedSql);
seedQuery.getSingleResult();
```

However, this query does not return any entity mapped by Hibernate, thus I'm receiving the following error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode (...)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-), `createQuery()` takes a [JPQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language) string, and apparently doesn't know what to do with your Postgres function call.

To run an SQL query, use [`createNativeQuery()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-) instead.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I noticed that I had to use `.createNativeQuery()` since `setseed()` is a function from PostgreSQL:

```
String seedsql = "select cast(setseed(0.123) as text)";
Query seedQuery = DatabaseInterface.getEm().createNativeQuery(seedsql);
seedQuery.setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();
```

I used `cast(setseed(0.123) as text)` to avoid another error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111